# BundleTransformer CSS/JS Minify not working

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, bundletransformer

I try to minify my JS and css with BundleTransformer.

If i run the Project with `BundleTable.EnableOptimiziations = false` the `@Styles.Render()` block isn't even rendered. The `@Scripts.Render()` will result in multiple  blocks without minification.

When i run the Project with `BUndleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` the `@Styles.Render()` will result in a link tag with `href="/Content/css/?v="`. The `@Scripts.Render()` will result in one script block with the url `"/Scripts/?v=TRhTmg-wH9HR9ogfgEbIlwetPksFTbcvK0b5873xXUg1"` which will lead to a directory listing and not a file.

If anyone has an idea what's going wrong, please give me advice.

The BundleConfig.cs looks like this

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public const string LessStyles = "~/Content/css/";
    public const string JavaScript = "~/Scripts/";

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleResolver.Current = new CustomBundleResolver();
        NullOrderer orderer = new NullOrderer();

        // Less bundle
        CustomStyleBundle styleBundle = new CustomStyleBundle(LessStyles)
        {
            Orderer = orderer
        };

        styleBundle.Include(
            "~/Scripts/pageLoadOverlay.css"
            , "~/Scripts/font.css"
            , "~/Scripts/bootmetro-icons.css"
            , "~/Scripts/bootmetro.css"
            , "~/Scripts/bootmetro-responsive.css"
            , "~/Scripts/metro-ui-dark.cs"
            , "~/Scripts/datepicker.css"
            , "~/Scripts/scrollbars.css"
            , "~/Scripts/colors-default.less"
            , "~/Scripts/general.less"
            , "~/Scripts/listview.less"
            , "~/Scripts/login.less"
            , "~/Scripts/maintenance.less"
            , "~/Scripts/modal.less"
            , "~/Scripts/rss.less"
            , "~/Scripts/slideDetail.less"
            , "~/Scripts/tiles.less"
            , "~/Scripts/timeline.less");

        bundles.Add(styleBundle);

        // JS Bundle
        CustomScriptBundle scriptBundle = new CustomScriptBundle(JavaScript);
        scriptBundle.Orderer = orderer;
        scriptBundle.Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        , "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"
        , "~/Scripts/monitor.web.util.js"
        , "~/Scripts/monitor.web.globals.js"
        , <some more JS files>);

        bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
    }
}
```

The BundleTransformer-Configuration block in web.config

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
    <core enableTracing="true">
        <css defaultPostProcessors="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" defaultMinifier="MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier">
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
                <add name="LessTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator, BundleTransformer.Less" />
            </translators>
            <postProcessors>
                <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="true" />
            </postProcessors>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
                <add name="MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax.Minifiers.MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" />
            </minifiers>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
                <add fileExtension=".less" assetTypeCode="Less" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </css>
        <js defaultPostProcessors=""
            defaultMinifier="MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier" usePreMinifiedFiles="true"
            combineFilesBeforeMinification="false">
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
            </translators>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
                <add name="MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier"
                     type="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax.Minifiers.MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" />
            </minifiers>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </js>
    </core>
    <less>
        <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
    </less>
    <microsoftAjax>
        <css allowEmbeddedAspNetBlocks="false" blocksStartOnSameLine="NewLine"
             ignoreAllErrors="false" ignoreErrorList="" indentSize="4"
             lineBreakThreshold="2147482647" outputMode="SingleLine"
             preprocessorDefineList="" termSemicolons="false"
             colorNames="Hex" commentMode="Important" minifyExpressions="true"
             removeEmptyBlocks="true" severity="0" />
        <js allowEmbeddedAspNetBlocks="false" blocksStartOnSameLine="NewLine"
            ignoreAllErrors="false" ignoreErrorList="" indentSize="4"
            lineBreakThreshold="2147482647" outputMode="SingleLine"
            preprocessorDefineList="" termSemicolons="false"
            alwaysEscapeNonAscii="false" amdSupport="false"
            collapseToLiteral="true" constStatementsMozilla="false"
            debugLookupList="Debug,$Debug,WAssert,Msn.Debug,Web.Debug"
            errorIfNotInlineSafe="false" evalLiteralExpressions="true"
            evalTreatment="Ignore" ignoreConditionalCompilation="false"
            ignorePreprocessorDefines="false" inlineSafeStrings="true"
            knownGlobalNamesList="" localRenaming="CrunchAll"
            macSafariQuirks="true" manualRenamesProperties="true"
            noAutoRenameList="$super" preserveFunctionNames="false"
            preserveImportantComments="true" quoteObjectLiteralProperties="false"
            removeFunctionExpressionNames="true" removeUnneededCode="true"
            renamePairs="" reorderScopeDeclarations="true"
            strictMode="false" stripDebugStatements="true"
            severity="0"/>
    </microsoftAjax>
</bundleTransformer>
```

And the referenced packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AjaxMin" version="5.14.5506.26202" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="BundleTransformer.Core" version="1.9.160" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="BundleTransformer.Less" version="1.9.160" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" version="1.9.160" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" version="2.4.10" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" version="2.4.10" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="MsieJavaScriptEngine" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```